# Does my .java file have to be on the same hardrive as my JDK? If not, why does CMD return java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, file, cmd, directory, execution

I am a rookie in Java, I finished the sololearn course and still practicing to memorize certain syntax. I got this Java, for dummies course book to read. I am getting to know the CI way to execute programs in Java. I made a simple hello world program in Notepad. I set the path variable. However my JDK is on my C hard drive and my program is in a folder on my E hard drive. Do my programs need to be in the same folder as my JDK. 
My JDK folder is located on my C drive so it looks like this

This `PC > (C:) > Program Files > Java`

My directory looks like this for my .java file that is trying to be executed

This `PC > (E:) > Programming`

The path environment looks like this

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;E:\Programming; // is the problem the spacing? :<
```

in CMD the command that I ran was: `java HelloApp.java`

I need help. The .java program is called: HelloApp.java.

in it is a simple HelloWorld program

Thanks
C0D3_X

Comment: You need to read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html.  Including the part that explains how to **compile** and run a Java program.

Comment: You don't need to have your `Programming` directory in the path, but you need to compile your program with `javac HelloApp.java` and run it with `java HelloApp`. It would be a very good idea to download Eclipse or at least VS Code to use as an editor instead of Notepad.

Comment: Yes ... but see my comment!  Oracle have written *lots of excellent tutorial material* for Java beginners.  The OP would be advised to invest the time in reading it.   In the long term it is a much better (efficient, effective, reliable) way to learn than starting by asking questions here.   At least, for basic things.

Answer (score 2):

> Do my programs need to be in the same folder as my JDK?

NO. they need not be.

> java HelloApp.java

That one is incorrect syntax to run java. You can not run like that,

Instead to compile use `javac HelloApp.java`

To run use `java HelloApp`

You have to also check whether your classpath is correctly set, if you do not change it the current directory is automatically included to the classpath.

Below error is mainly because of java could not find the class files, check your classpath contains the current directory.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```